# Start Service as Foreground or Not for Oreo Restriction

Tags: illegalstateexception

I want to show notification only if i am in background

Basically i want to avoid the notification as much as possible, Plus i want to make sure Notification is not creating much noise and irritation(vibration) to the user

Oreo hates me starting service in background and draining battery

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1 && AmInBackground(context)) 
    {
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
        showNotification();
    }
    else
    {
        context.startService(intent);
    }  

    ----------

    private boolean AmInBackground(Context context){
            ActivityManager activityManager = 
                 (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = 
                                           activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
            String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.baseActivity.getPackageName();
            boolean same = foregroundTaskPackageName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName());
            return !same;
    }


    ----------

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, CHANNEL_ID).setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText("Service is running in the background")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setSound(null)// No Sound
                    .setVibrate(null) // No Vibration
                    .setDefaults(~DEFAULT_SOUND) // Remove Default sound
                    .setDefaults(~DEFAULT_VIBRATE) // Remove Default Vibration
                    .build();
```

*I Kill my service once my work is done, This will help in pull off my notification from the notification bar.*

I use startForegroundService only if my work is dependent on some other task.

If i have a independent task and full control of what to do and when to do.
then i use job scheduler Api, its pretty cool, with Back off logic